# Android Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x14 in tid 29469 (JDWP)

Tags: android, jdwp

**Each time when I attach a debug thread to Android studio ,  run to breakpoint, the app crashes. Here is the crash stack, can some one tell me why and give me some advice to solve it, thanks a lot!:**

```
09-30 13:53:43.250 29461 29469 F libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x14 in tid 29469 (JDWP)
09-30 13:53:43.367 30057 30057 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***                             *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
09-30 13:53:43.367 30057 30057 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint:         'Xiaomi/chiron/chiron:8.0.0/OPR1.170623.027/V10.0.1.0.ODECNFH:user/release-keys'
09-30 13:53:43.367 30057 30057 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
09-30 13:53:43.367 30057 30057 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm'
09-30 13:53:43.368 30057 30057 F DEBUG   : pid: 29461, tid: 29469, name: JDWP      >>> com.taobao.taobao <<<
09-30 13:53:43.368 30057 30057 F DEBUG   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1     (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x14
09-30 13:53:43.368 30057 30057 F DEBUG   : Cause: null pointer dereference
09-30 13:53:43.368 30057 30057 F DEBUG   :     r0 00000000  r1 0000ffff  r2     0000ffff  r3 00000001
09-30 13:53:43.368 30057 30057 F DEBUG   :     r4 00000000  r5 ecfadc20  r6         e31a3698  r7 ecbbb269
09-30 13:53:43.368 30057 30057 F DEBUG   :     r8 e31a375f  r9 0000004d  sl 00000020  fp ecf1fc40
09-30 13:53:43.368 30057 30057 F DEBUG   :     ip 00000000  sp e31a3648  lr ecabde45  pc ecabde4c  cpsr 600f0030
09-30 13:53:43.370 30057 30057 F DEBUG   :
09-30 13:53:43.370 30057 30057 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
09-30 13:53:43.370 30057 30057 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 0013ee4c  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11annotations23GetSourceDebugExtensionENS_6HandleINS_6mirror5ClassEEE+63)
09-30 13:53:43.370 30057 30057 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 0011a4f9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3Dbg23GetSourceDebugExtensionEyPNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEE+196)
09-30 13:53:43.370 30057 30057 F DEBUG   :     #02 pc 0023c289  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWPL23RT_SourceDebugExtensionEPNS0_9JdwpStateEPNS0_7RequestEPNS0_9ExpandBufE+32)
09-30 13:53:43.370 30057 30057 F DEBUG   :     #03 pc 0023ae0d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState14ProcessRequestEPNS0_7RequestEPNS0_9ExpandBufEPb+584)
09-30 13:53:43.370 30057 30057 F DEBUG   :     #04 pc 00240115  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState12HandlePacketEv+120)
09-30 13:53:43.370 30057 30057 F DEBUG   :     #05 pc 003e7e5f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP12JdwpAdbState15ProcessIncomingEv+730)
09-30 13:53:43.370 30057 30057 F DEBUG   :     #06 pc 00240449  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState3RunEv+440)
09-30 13:53:43.370 30057 30057 F DEBUG   :     #07 pc 0023fbc7  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWPL15StartJdwpThreadEPv+22)
09-30 13:53:43.370 30057 30057 F DEBUG   :     #08 pc 0004841f  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+22)
09-30 13:53:43.370 30057 30057 F DEBUG   :     #09 pc 0001b55d  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+32)
```

**Here is the my Android Studio info**

```
 Android Studio 3.1.4
 Build #AI-173.4907809, built on July 24, 2018
 JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01 x86_64
 JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
 Mac OS X 10.13.6
```

**Here is the image of my breakpoint**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBoTW.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The breakpoint inside java.lang.reflect.Proxy cause the crash. 
Log at the breakpoint(The last line): 

    `at retrofit2.Retrofit.nextResponseBodyConverter(Retrofit.java:330)
    at retrofit2.Retrofit.responseBodyConverter(Retrofit.java:313)
    at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.createResponseConverter(ServiceMethod.java:736)
    at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.build(ServiceMethod.java:169)
    at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:170)
    at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:147)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:913)`

This is a bug of Android VM. The Crash Message: 

    `Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x14 in tid 14802 (JDWP)`